# How do I user htaccess to suppress an URL path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this url `http://localhost/dev/mysite/public/index.html` and `http://localhost/dev/mysite/manager/index.php` I want to suppress only the `/public/` path to be 
`http://localhost/dev/mysite/`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following rule to the htaccess file should achieve this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [R=302]
```

(Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect is working.

EDIT:

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dev/mysite/public/(.*) /dev/mysite/$1 [R=302]
```

Comment: This works if it is on production. Do you know how to do it on dev?
only `http://localhost/dev/mysite/public/` to `http://localhost/dev/mysite/`

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post. That will only remove `public` from urls that have `dev/mysite/public/` in it.

Comment: Thank you for share your knowledge! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If this helped you, you can mark the answer as correct (the tick below the arrows on the left) so other people who has your problem can know how you solved it.